# Is it possible to use `__sec_implicit_index` inside an `if` block statement using Cilk Plus Array Notation?

Tags: c++, arrays, conditional-statements, cilk, cilk-plus

My goal is to conditionally assign values to an array based on the implicit index value, using Cilk Plus Array Notation with Intel's `icc` compiler, version `13.1.3 20130607`.

Consider the following code:

```
    T test[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    if(test[:] < 5) {
        test[:] = 10 - __sec_implicit_index(0);
    }
```

This code compiles fine, but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
undefined symbol: __sec_implicit_index
```

**Note** Although this might look like a linking error, it is not, since the following code compiles and runs fine *(the condition has been removed)*:

```
T test[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
test[:] = 10 - __sec_implicit_index(0);
```

So, my question: is it possible to accomplish the behaviour of the conditional code below using Cilk Plus Array Notation?

```
    T test[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(i < 5) {
            test[i] = 10 - i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is correct.  The problem is a bug in icc 13.1.3.  icc 14.0 beta correctly compiled and executed the example for me.

For icc 13.1.3, I have found #pragma simd to be more reliable, in general, as a way to indicate permission to vectorize.  With it, your example looks like:

```
T test[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
#pragma simd
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(i < 5) {
        test[i] = 10 - i;
    }
}
```

It of course loses the notational convenience of array notation.

Comment: Thanks, that's great!  Also, thanks for the tip about `#pragma simd`!  I now remember skimming past that in the documentation, but had totally forgotten about it.